# Adding IBAN defaults to stripe's PaymentElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

The [react-stripe-js](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js) `IbanElement` [offers options](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/blob/master/types/stripe-js/elements/iban.d.ts#L104) like `supportedCountries` and `placeholderCountry`:

```js
<IbanElement
  ...
  options={{
    supportedCountries: ["SEPA"],
    placeholderCountry: "DE",
  }}
/>
```

but the recently published `PaymentElement` [does not](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/blob/master/types/stripe-js/elements/payment.d.ts#L137):

```js
<PaymentElement
  ...
  options={{
    ???
  }}
/>
```

Is there a way to add these defaults to a `PaymentElement` whose `clientSecret` is configured with `sepa_debit` [in its `payment_method_types`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-payment_method_types)?

Answer (score 0):

For Payment Element, `supportedCountries` does not need to be defined as Payment Element automatically determines which payment methods to display [0], based on:

- The customer’s location.
- The product’s currency.
- Your Dashboard settings on which payment methods to accept [1].

The `placeholderCountry` is not available for customisation.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element
[1] https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payment_methods

Comment: Right -- it's cool that stripe.js automatically determines the displayable methods etc but I'd like to prefill certain data like the country (which I store separately anyways). Why does the `PaymentElement` not support the same options as the `IbanElem` that it's designed to "replace"?