# Specifying mandate[notification_method] client-side with Stripe.js?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm creating reusable SEPA source by first [creating a `client_secret` server-side](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create?lang=node):

```js
await stripe.setupIntents.create({
  payment_method_types: ["sepa_debit"],
  customer: "..."
});
```

I then pass the `client_secret` to `<Elements />` as an option:

```js
<Elements
  stripe={...}
  options={{
    locale,
    clientSecret: setupIntentClientSecret,
    ...
  }}
>
```

Once the customer enters their SEPA debit data, I [confirm the setup](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_setup) client-side via:

```js
await stripe.confirmSetup({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    return_url: window.location.href
  },
  redirect: "if_required"
})
```

Now, the [SEPA debit best practices](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sepa-debit#using-webhooks-or-automated-emails) mention that

> Source objects provide tooling to help you notify your users compliantly. At Source creation it is possible to specify a mandate[notification_method].

So how can I specify this `mandate` attribute client-side? I suppose it simply isn't possible and I'll need to [update the newly created source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/update?lang=node#update_source-mandate) server-side?

EDIT:
Source updating won't work because the object created by calling `stripe.confirmSetup` is a `payment_method`, not a `source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you've shared ([link](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/sepa-debit#using-webhooks-or-automated-emails)) is for the older SEPA integration path using the Sources API. Instead, you should refer to [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/sepa-debit/set-up-payment?platform=web#web-collect-payment-method-details) which references mandate collection and uses the new APIs including Setup Intents, Payment Methods and the Payment Element (as per the code you've shared).

Comment: Thanks -- I'm already using the new guide incl `SetupIntents`. I only included the old guide because it's the only documentation that explains the `mandate` notification option. The guide you linked is itself a bit outdated because stripe recommends to [migrate](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element/migration#recurring-update-method) `<IbanElement />` to `<PaymentElement />`. That migration itself has its downsides ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70518709/8160318)) but I digress. I simply need to figure out how these mandate notifications work with `SeupIntents`

Comment: At the end of the day, I'll need to react to [`source.mandate_notification`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types?lang=node#event_types-source.mandate_notification) webhooks. Are you saying that if I create a sepa debit payment method using `SetupIntents`, this webhook won't be fired because it only applies to the outdated `Sources`?

Comment: The Elements used are interchangeable, really. You can switch out to the Payment Element if you intend to offer multiple different payment methods to your customers. That's the key difference.

Comment: Yes, the Setup Intent will create a Payment Method object. Not a Source. Payment Methods were introduced to replace Sources, so any `source.*` event won't fire in this case.

Comment: OK that makes sense - thanks. What about `Setup` mandates? Is this concept entirely deprecated?

Comment: In the case of the payment notifications, [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/sepa-debit#debit-notification-emails) is the recommended integration path for handling mandate notifications with the Payment Methods/Payment Intents APIs.